# What is the default if I install virtualenv using pip and pip3 respectively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I used `sudo pip install virtualenv`, then when I run `virtualenv ENV` in a directory, I get a Python 2 virtual enviroment.

If I use 'pip3 install virtualenv' to install virtualenv again, will it override the previous installation of virtualenv, then when I run `virtualenv ENV`, I get a Python 3 virtual enviroment? or will it install a new virtualenv in a different name like virtualenv3 in a different place ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to go to those lengths. You can use Python 2's `virtualenv` to create a Python 3 virtual environment. Supposing you have Python 3's binary installed at `/usr/local/bin/python3` then simply run

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 ENV
```

and you will find that

```
source ENV/bin/activate
```

gives you the Python 3 environment you want.